# If a laptop/Computer support both Ethernet and WiFi then does the system have different NIC for Ethernet and WiFi or same?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have seen there are two different MAC for Ethernet and WiFi.So,I wanted to know that the both MAC is hard coded in the same NIC or both have separate NIC.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 MAC addresses then you have 2 interfaces from the point of view of your TCP/IP stack.  One will be wired Ethernet, the other will be Wifi.  Each can have a separate IP, etc. and be active at the same time.

On most PC and ARM motherboards the wired NIC and Wifi controller will be separate physical chips, either soldered on the mainboard or on a PCI/PCIe card.  It's common for a Wifi controller to also have Bluetooth.

It's probably not impossible for a manufacturer to build a single chip or device that has wired Ethernet and Wifi in one physical device or package.  I don't know of any real life examples.

But it wouldn't change anything - most standards that allow a device to talk to a CPU support some notion of "subdevices" - PCI, Thunderbolt, USB all do.  One PCI card or USB device can actually look like and be treated as multiple devices by the OS, for example.

So under most usual hardware situations the operating system would still present 2 separate NICs to the OS regardless of what is really going on in the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

They're separate NICs. Wired and wireless NICs being combined into one is unheard of.

Comment: Both being combined into one chip is quite common, though.